# C# color code not working properly how can I fix this?

Tags: c#

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiPN9.jpg

Loads of my code in C# is white-colored, why is this and how can I fix it?

I have tried playing around in VScode settings with no luck.

Comment: Code not working, or code not colored to your liking?

Comment: What is not working properly? That you want a different color? That doesn't mean it isn't working. It just means you want to customize it. And, if that's possible, it would be done through the options or settings.

Comment: This link shows how to change the theme https://www.techjunkie.com/visual-studio-change-theme/

Comment: You can use various extensions in VSCode to change it theme, however it is totally configurable. And you can see this reference for furthur information  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in your screenshot that is white that shouldn't be according to most standard color schemes. If you highlight specific examples of what is white that you think shouldn't be, and explain why you think they shouldn't be, I will edit in whatever explanation seems to fit.

As it stands, I see nothing wrong here other than you using namespaces like `System` and `System.Drawing` that should be in using declarations at the top of your file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It appears I didn't play around with the color themes in VS code quite enough. Found the one I was looking for (Dark+). Cheers